# Better way to manage Windows Firewall - more than 2 profiles/rulesets, and setting scopes on traffic, simpler than advanced firewall UI?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-firewall

I don't really find the standard profiles for a non-domain PC very helpful or well suited to my needs. But the only alternative I know is to set hundreds of rules in "Advanced Firewall".

I'm hoping that somewhere in Windows Firewall is access to multiple profiles/rulesets and ways to set rules applying to groups of programs/protocols, or something like that, which gives me a nicer way to manage Windows Firewall that better fits my needs, or at worst some kind of software that helps configure the rules and rulesets like I want it, if that's needed.

**WHAT THE "STANDARD/SIMPLE" FIREWALL UI ALLOWS**:

The kinds of rules that the UI allows for non-domain PCs * without * setting individual *advanced rules* are:

1. Two network profiles/rulesets can be defined, called "private" and "public". 2. For each of these, the user can specify which programs/protocols can connect to, and be connected from, anywhere on the internet. The only option available is "completely on, bidirectional" or "blocked". Nothing in between.

**WHAT IT DOESN'T ALLOW:**

1. Create other profiles/rulesets (say you have >=3 categories of network which networks fall into, not just 2);
2. Specify within a profile/ruleset, limitations on the scope of any given traffic (LAN only/any IP, outward only/bidirectional).

**WHAT I WANT TO MANAGE IT:**

Those last 2 bullets are what I'm after. I kind of remember that it used to be that way (a bit) in the early versions of Windows Firewall GUI (XP era), but it isn't there now, or else I can't find it.

Is there an easy way to manage the firewall like this, without having to customise all the "advanced firewall" rules in detail for each and every item, and to transfer the settings to other PCs? It would make life so much easier.

I don't even mind if it's a non-Microsoft util (one that makes it easier to set the Windows Firewall rules I want, not a firewall/AV product that adds its own FW). That would be better than nothing, but I'd prefer a nice way to do it in Windows.  But I want an end to managing the minutiae of advanced firewall UI - it's such an inefficient approach for this!

Comment: You can use `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule` command to add rule. You can export/import firewall rules to many PC with `netah advfirewall export` command. What do you mean by "limitations on the scope of any given traffic"?

Comment: Scope = local subnet vs entire internet, or block both/one/no directions, rather than just traffic=yes/no. But this isn't really answering the Q. I know I can do it rule at a time, using Advanced FW UI/netsh. But it's so cumbersome for something that's both basic and essential, like this program needing "block both directions" and that needing "block incoming only", or "block out all" vs "allow local subnet only" vs "allow out any". They're so ... basic..!  There's **got** to be a better way to enter them for a program than piecemeal via CLI or individual advanced rules UI...? But how?